# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException On simply populating spinner from string array or list or xml file(strings.xml)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I want to populate **spinner** through String array or through XML file(strings.xml). But I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException:` error. I have searched a lot on google but it is worthless. What I have tried is like below.

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.android02.personalityinsight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    Spinner sp1, sp2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

//        String colors[] = {"Red", "Blue", "White", "Yellow", "Black", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Grey"};
//        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
//
//        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
//        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//        sp1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.ans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Personality Insights"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Quiz"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("PI v/s Quiz"));

        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabs.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_submit:
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        int mNumOfTabs;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int mNumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
        }

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return TabOne_Fragment.newInstance();
                case 1:
                    return TanTwo_Fragment.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return TabThree_Fragment.newInstance();
                default:
                    return TabOne_Fragment.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

tabtwo_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="Sitting and reading: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="Sitting, inactive in a public place (e.g. a theatre or a meeting): "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">PersonalityInsight</string>
    <!-- Custom -->
    <string name="facebook_app_id">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>

    <string-array name="ans">
        <item>Zero</item>
        <item>One</item>
        <item>Two</item>
        <item>Three</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvIr3.png)

However I am getting error at this line `sp2.setAdapter(adapter);` no matter I am filling spinner from **ARRAY** or from **XML** file. I have tried filling spinner with List too but same error occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says your adapter is null.

Try change your adapter initialise your adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.ans);
```

**Edit**

Actually you know what, why not do it in your xml file instead, like this:

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/sp1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
       android:entries="@array/ans"
       android:prompt="@string/select_one"/>
```

**EDIT2**

Since you prefer to do it programmatically, try:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ans)); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

- `R.array.ans` changed to `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ans)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29

Comment: It gives **ERROR** at `R.array.ans` and says **Expected resource of type id**. By the way see `sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);` lines, which are commented. Are you trying to say to do like that?@Jiyeh

Comment: As you told I have added attributes to Spinner and updated my SecondActivity.java file as like `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.ans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);` But same error.@Jiyeh

Comment: Check updated answer again. Should work now. @MaulikM.Dodia

Comment: I have changed the code as per you said. But error remains same. By the way, I have ViewPager in SecondActivity and using Fragment in ViewPager. And these spinners are in one of Fragments i.e Second Fragment. I have also tried to write that code in onCreateView method of TabTwoFragment.java file but It prints nothing.@Jiyeh

Comment: Ahh I see. Since your Spinner is in your fragment, so you should declare it in `onCreateView()` of your Fragment, but not in `onCreate()` of your Activity. I will add another answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you make your Spinner in your Fragment, when you try to find your Spinner s1/s2 in your activity by `findViewById()`, it isn't there and that's what NPE thrown.

So I think you should instead populate the Spinner in your Fragment `onCreateView()`.

And you can do it like this: [Error populating spinner in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351691/error-populating-spinner-in-a-fragment/12935831#12935831)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**  -->  Add your array into string.xml file

For example

```
<string-array name="ans">
        <item>Zero</item>
        <item>One</item>
        <item>Two</item>
        <item>Three</item>
    </string-array>
```

**Step 2**   add this array to your spinner xml

**android:entries="@array/ans"**

**Step 3** In your java file

```
 Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I do not want to create spinner programmatically. I have that spinner in my layout file bro.@Arpit Patel

Comment: So don't need to that adapter just put android:entries="@array/ans" in your xml file

Comment: Yes. I have done it. And accepted @Jiyeh answer.@Arpit Patel