# How to use spinner created in a fragment layout to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a spinner created in fragment_tab.xml . I tried to populate the spinner from an arrayadapter in MainActivity but it is giving null pointer exception. 
My question is, what is the specific way to do that? After searching a lot, i failed to find the way.
Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
Spinner spinner;
List<String> places;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabLayoutConfigure();
    AddSpinner();
}


public void tabLayoutConfigure()
{
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

public void AddSpinner()
{
    this.spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    places= new ArrayList<String>();
    places.add("Regional office");
    places.add("Farm office");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,places);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
      });
  }
}
```

Here is my TabFragment class(Fragment):

```
public class TabFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab,container,false);
 }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/textColorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#689F38"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Enrollment place"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner" />
```

Any suggestion will be a great help!

Comment: Update: the xml files are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by adding a method in the fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab,container,false);
    AddSpinner(view);
    return view;
}

public void AddSpinner(View view)
{
    spinner= (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    places= new ArrayList<String>();
    places.add("Regional office");
    places.add("Farm office");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,places);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Using
    spinner= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner) 
is solving the issue.
Special thanks to Praveen Pandey and this question: [Error populating spinner in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351691/error-populating-spinner-in-a-fragment/12935831#12935831)

Answer (score 3):

I am not very sure on what you are trying to achieve , but I see that you are initialising the spinner in activity , have you declared the "R.id.spinner" in the fragment layout or activity layout . If you have declared it in the fragment layout the activity will not be able to find the view . you can move the spinner code in your fragment .

However if you can post you activity and fragment xml it will be easy to figure out .

Comment: Yes, I agree that you should move method to your fragment. Something like `populateSpinner(ArrayList<String> items)`, and then just reference fragment from the main class, and use that method on that reference, passing the array argument.

Comment: @Praveen, yes I declared the spinner in the fragment layout, and that's the mistake. I want to find the view in activity. Please help.

Comment: @SefatNoor I am not able to understand the purpose of declaring the view in fragment if you want to initialise it in the activity , however if you want to listen to the spinner selection in the activity you can implement callbacks to handle that , please let me know what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: Actually, as the spinner is in fragment layout, How can I be able to populate it in the fragment activity?